# Drop Shadow in DrawRect

Tags: uiview, xcode4, drawrect, dropshadow

I made this cool pie chart and now I'd like to drop a shadow under it.
Is there anyway I can do it with DrawRect ?

[image]

I'd like to do it right under the pie chart (drawn using DrawRect).
Suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at BNPiechart here - http://bynomial.com/blog/?p=104 . The code is open source.You can use it directly.If you do not want to use the library, you can refer the code for creating the shadow.

Comment: that's just perfect. There's a simple line for this but after reading the whole material it made me open my eyes for so much drawRect can do... Here's what I was looking for exactly (but you should check the entire material this guy posted. Thanks man!

Comment: CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context, shadowOffset, shadowBlurRadius, shadowColor.CGColor);